# TYPO3 10.4.12 optionSplit in IMAGE srcset

Tags: typo3, typo3-10.x

In my TypoScript object the optionSplit failed. Always a comma is added in srcset and W3C validator said: Bad value for attribute srcset on element img: Ends with empty image-candidate string.

This TypoScript snippet

```
        layoutKey = srcset
        layout {
          srcset {
            element = <img src="###SRC###" srcset="###SOURCECOLLECTION###" ###PARAMS### ###ALTPARAMS### ###SELFCLOSINGTAGSLASH###>
            source = ###SRC### ###SRCSETCANDIDATE###,|*|###SRC### ###SRCSETCANDIDATE###,|*|###SRC### ###SRCSETCANDIDATE###
          }
        }
```

results in

```
<img src="/storage/shared/hochschule/labels/swissuniversities-logo.png"
  srcset="
    /storage/_processed_/5/6/csm_swissuniversities-logo_685d915ef8.png 687w,
    /storage/_processed_/5/6/csm_swissuniversities-logo_57966614b3.png 436w,
    /storage/_processed_/5/6/csm_swissuniversities-logo_74d43a23bf.png 255w," 
  class="image-embed-item img-fluid" 
  sizes="(max-width: 767px) 687px, (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) 436px, (min-width: 992px) 255px" alt="">
```

Is this a bug?

Comment: Just by looking at the source I would say the first delimiter `|*|` is wrong and needs to be deleted.

Comment: Does not change anything. Example from doc https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/master/en-us/ContentObjects/Image/Index.html don't work. Always have a comma after last item.

Comment: I changed my question and remove first |*|. But nothing changed.

Comment: not everything is capable of optionsplit. have you tried whether optionsplit is working at all in your context? (What do you see if you set `A |*| B |*| C` instead of your strings? is it more than one letter?)

Comment: Output is srcset="AAA". It should be ABC if optionSplit works. Right? Example is taken from official docs https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/master/en-us/ContentObjects/Image/Index.html

Answer (score 0):

Optionsplit only has three values (per level). the separation on main level is done by `|*|`, the second level separation is `||`. As the default wrap-separation is `|` you could get a confusion if you miss some spaces. Especially if one side of the wrap is empty.

as you can remove values, you can work with only one separator, but you can't include more values. you also can ommit the `|*|` separators at all and only use second level separators `||`

The first (before the first separator) or only 'normal' wrapping is the beginning, then following the middle part. And after a second separator the ending part.

more confusion can be generated if you use `optionSplit` with the wrapping `.noTrimWrap` where there also are `|` separators around the whole wrap. So be careful with your separators and spaces.

Comment: Thank you for the explaining. Three delimeter is wrong. But no matter how I try to split I always have a comma at the end. optionSplit should begin at the right side, but does not.

Comment: you should understand the order of wraps for optionsplit. there are a lot of examples in the [Typoscript Reference](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/10.4/en-us/Functions/OptionSplit.html#three-by-one-items)